# Show MessageBox inside Pastinghandler WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, event-handling

I have a dialog where the user can edit some fields. There are 3 specific ones that have a validation. For these fields I created a pastinghandler like the following:

```
DataObject.AddPastingHandler(myTextBox, numericValidatorHandler);
```

When I try to show a messagebox inside the handler I get an exception. It seems like the paste runs in a different thread...

My workaround at the moment was to use a backgroundworker and set two events DoWork and RunWorkerCompleted.

In the first one I set the result with some args I pass from the numericValidatorHandler by the 'Argument' property

'numericValidatorHandler'

```
bw.RunWorkerAsync(args);
```

....

'DoWorkHandler'

```
e.Result = e.Argument;
```

....

'RunWorkerCompletedHandler'

```
//Here I just use e.Result to create an output message for the messagebox
```

Is there a easier way to show a MessageBox inside a past eventhandler?

Comment: Delegate the call back to the UI thread via the `Dispatcher`?

Comment: I tried defining a ThreadStart delegate and invoking it with the dispatcher and passing the arguments. It works if I don't use a string[] as arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a work item onto the UI thread work item queue using the `Dispatcher` class. Try this:

```
public void DataObjectPastingEventHandler(object sender, DataObjectPastingEventArgs e) 
{
    Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke((Action)delegate()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Hello");
    });
}
```

---

UPDATE >>>

There are a couple of things that you can try... the first is for you to initialise the `Dispatcher` to be on the UI thread. Call this in the `Window` constructor or in a `Loaded` event handler, where you can be sure the UI thread is running:

```
Dispatcher uiDispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;
```

If that doesn't fix the problem, then you can also try to run the original method asynchronously:

```
public void DataObjectPastingEventHandler(object sender, DataObjectPastingEventArgs e) 
{
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)delegate()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Hello");
    }, null);
}
```

If *that* still doesn't work, then I'm all out of ideas... I would just find somewhere else to launch the `MessageBox` from.

Comment: I tried this solution but the exception was a different one ""Cannot perform this operation while dispatcher processing is suspended.""

Comment: From my Dispatcher I cannot access the "CurrentDispatcher" property. Your hint was very helpful. Through Dispatcher just with an asynch. call

Answer (score 0):

Like some of you said, with the Dispatcher this was more straightforward

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)delegate(){
    MessageBox.Show("Cannot Paste ...");
}, null);
```